# How to import nested interfaces in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, nested

**It Typescript when I import nested interfaces the predictatext in VS code shows me items in the high level interface but not in the nested one.**

There is a [key:string] in the "Example" interface does this mean I cannot use the predictatext for data structures of this sort (even though it will check type safety), or is it just not working as I have set it up incorrectly.

## Example

```
export interface Item {
    id: number;
    size: number;
}
export interface Example {
    name: string;
    items: {
        [key: string]: Item
    };
}
```

Then file 2

```
import {Example, Item} from '../utils/interfaces'

const obj = {
    name: "test",
    items: {
        "a": {
            id: 1,
            size: 10
        },
        "b": {
            id: 2,
            size: 34
        }
    }
}
```

## RESULT

The predictertext works for the first level interface but not after that eg

```
console.log(obj.            // predictatext offers two options: items & names
console.log(obj.items.      // predictatext offers :    NOTHING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the nested interfaces. The following won't autocomplete either:

```js
interface Example {
   [key: string]: number
}
```

It *can't* autocomplete because the key could be anything. Similarly, anything after `obj.items.` is valid.

If only certain items are allowed, you would have to specify them in the interface.

Comment: Ahh! So All I have to do is persist I just tested it and you are correct. example here eg console.log(obj.items.a.{then I get autocomplete once I fill in a}). Thanks!

Comment: I actually hadn't realised that was your question, so I'm glad you figured it out! Btw, I just noticed that the object is const. If the object won't change, you can write `as const` at the end and you will have autocomplete and type safety for that object in particular, but I don't know if that's actually your case.